# 802.11ac incredibly slow file transfers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've just upgraded my whole network to 802.11ac - new router as well as new 802.11ac USB sticks for every computer that doesn't support it out of the box.

For some reason my read and write speeds are horrible, I have 2 PC's setup next to each other with the router not more than 3 meters away (clear sight, no walls).

On both PC's the Wireless connection status shows me a speed of 450+ Mbps, yet if I copy one file to the other I'm getting a maximum transfer rate of 5MB/s

To eliminate the possibility that the USB sticks are the culprit here, I did run the same test from iMac to MacBookPro both supporting 802.11ac out of the box (Both devices approx. 3 meters away from the router, no walls either)

The connection's stats:

- PHY Mode: 802.11ac
- 5GHz
- Transmit Rate: 527

The outcome:

- Writing: 9.84 Mbit/s - 1.2MB/s
- Reading: 65 Mbit/s - 8MB/s

I think I have tried every possible settings in the router, I have completely disabled a/b/g/n, tried changing the MHz - updated to latest firmware, all to no avail.

The router model is a D-Link DIR-820L

Comment: Is it possible the router is overheating? This can happen if ventilation is blocked. Does anything improve if you turn it off and leave if for a while before turning it back on? Also, most routers have a WiFi status page that shows signal level, SNR etc. - what does it say?

Comment: Signal is 96%, what is weird in the router status page it says the devices is connected with a rate of 144.5M, while the windows Wireless connection status says 433.5M ?

Comment: What model USB sticks? There are many flavors of 802.11ac, from no-faster-than-802.11n, to nearly 7Gbps (although no one's shipping anything better than 1.3Gbps as of this writing), with many many stops in between. Without knowing which 802.11ac flavors your USB sticks are capable of, it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: @spiff The Sticks are D-Link as welll, model DWA-171 - they are only used on the PC's since the Macs have built-in 802.11ac

Answer (score 1):

It may very well turn out that the D-Link DIR-820L has a crappy 802.11ac AP implementation. Most 802.11ac APs are top-of-the-line, flagship devices for around $180, that hit the 1300Mbps data rate, which requires:

- 3 spatial streams
- VHT80 (80MHz-wide channels)
- MCS 9 (256-QAM)
- short guard intervals (SGI)

Slightly less expensive ones only hit the 867Mbps data rate, which requires all of the above except just 2 spatial streams instead of 3.

This device only does a 650Mbps data rate, which probably means that not only does it not do 3 spatial stream, it also doesn't do MCS 8 or 9 (256-QAM).

Note that I'm only talking about the 5GHz 802.11ac performance by itself, I'm not falling for the marking BS where they add their 2.4GHz 802.11n performance to their 5GHz 802.11ac performance.

Anyway, the fact that they can't do 3 spatial streams and can't do 256-QAM is a sign that they made some deep compromises to hit that $75 price. I also note that it only has 100Mbps, not Gigabit, Ethernet LAN ports. Further evidence of corner-cutting that hurts performance.

---

To really see what that AP is capable of, you need to do a performance test that eliminates the overhead of disk I/O and remote filesystem protocols like SMB and AFP.

I usually recommend that one endpoint of your performance test be on a wired Ethernet LAN port of the AP, but since this AP's wired Ethernet isn't Gigabit, that'll be the bottleneck. The best you could possibly do is 94 Mbps = 11 MiBytes/sec.

So to see something better than 11MiB/sec, you have to do a wireless-to-wireless test, but that will cut your Wi-Fi performance in half.

So anyway, associate your 802.11ac iMac and 802.11ac retina MacBook Pro to the 5GHz network, and run IPerf on each. Make the iMac the IPerf server, and make the retina MacBook Pro the IPerf client. On both ends, add the `-w 2M` option to the IPerf command-line so that you have a nice big TCP window to work with.

Make sure all three devices are at least 2m apart from each other so they aren't saturating each others' receivers.

If all goes well, and they're all able to sustain the 650Mbps signaling rate that your AP tops out at, I'd expect you to see a max throughput of 260Mbps, which is 31MiB/sec.

The calculation goes like this:

1. Take the signaling rate (PHY rate) the devices are able to sustain.
2. Divide it in half since both devices are sharing the wireless medium and the AP is having to do Intra-BSS Relay, which means every packets is sent across the channel twice; once from the source device to the AP, and then again from the AP to the destination device.
3. Take 80% of that (i.e. multiply it by 0.8) to account for Wi-Fi overhead, assuming frame aggregation (A-MPDU).

So (650/2)*0.8 = 260Mbps. 260/8.4 = 31MiB/sec (8.4 is to convert from 10^6 bits to 2^20 Bytes).

Comment: Thanks for your very extensive answer, I would have loved to buy another 802.11ac AP unfortunately that was the only one I could find going through about 10 shops (I live in Thailand). I will run the test you suggested and report back.

Comment: The Result of iperf: ------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.0.103, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 2.00 MByte (WARNING: requested 2.00 MByte)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.0.102 port 62896 connected with 192.168.0.103 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  60.5 MBytes  50.7 Mbits/sec

Comment: So that's atleast 200Mbps less than what I should be getting ?

Comment: @Fred It looks like you can buy an 802.11ac AirPort Extreme on the Thai version of the online Apple Store: http://store.apple.com/th/product/ME918TH/A/airport-extreme .

Comment: @Fred Yes, it looks like you're getting 200Mbps less than you should be getting. Can you make sure your D-Link AP's 5GHz radio is configured for 80MHz-wide channels? If you option-click on the Wi-Fi Menu Extra in OS X, what additional diagnostic info do you see in grey text? It would be nice to know your transmit rate, MCS index, and channel.

Comment: It won't let me configure for 80MHz exclusively, rather it says : Auto (20/40/80) - rest is configured like this: `Wireless Band:    5GHz Band
Wireless Radio:    Enable
802.11 Mode :    802.11ac only
Channel Width:    20/40/80 MHz
Channel:    161` I don't know if the channel really matters, since there is no other 5GHz network anywhere around me. If I option click on the Wi-Fi Menu, I can't see anything about MCS index, channel is the same: 161, Transmit rate hovers around 400, it was showing 867 previously when I was closer to the router for the testing.

Comment: Also, is the Airport Extreme any good ? I'm kind of worried about not having any (visible / adjustable) antennas, I've had another router before the D-Link one without visible / adjustable antennas and my signal was very poor just being 10 meters away and 1 wall in between my MacBook and the router, same trouble now but not as bad with the D-Link one, in the same location i'm getting around 35% signal according to the router config page, which is very odd considering I'm being really close to the router.

Comment: I've just found the MCS Index, in System Information, it's 3

Comment: @Fred It doesn't make sense that your client's transmit rate could have been 867 when your AP only supports 650. Unless your router has a bug that it advertises support for data rates it really doesn't support, or your Mac has a bug that it ignores the advertised rates and tries to use higher rates anyway.

Comment: @Fred The 802.11ac AirPort Extreme is excellent. It has a great antenna array underneath the radome (the plastic top of the enclosure), and it has high-power transmit amplifiers (PAs) and high-quality Low-Noise Amplifiers (LNAs) on receive, giving it great range. It performs very well and is easy to set up and manage.

Comment: @Fred Did you look up that MCS Index while in the testing position, or further away? Because MCS 3 suggests a PHY rate of 260, not "around 400".

Comment: Apparently the rate was not the same when I was in System Information, looks like it jumps around a lot, now I get  Transmit Rate: 390
  MCS Index: 9

Comment: Also, to confirm I am not crazy, [transmit rate when taking my MBP close to the router](http://imgur.com/EKFlGAP) at 780!

Comment: Also interesting, I've just ran a couple more tests, on my PC result is this: [Test 1 PC](http://imgur.com/z4h7vBR) this is writing to my NAS storage connected through the 100mbit port of the router. Now the same test on the iMac [Test 2 iMac](http://imgur.com/N7I872R) note that I didn't use the same file size on the Mac because writing would take ages.

Comment: I just bought a Airport Extreme, Transmit rate on iMac 867, copying files to NAS 1MB/s -- Transmit rate on PC 433.5 copying files from PC to NAS, 30MB/s - Exact same results, PC got faster, iMac no improvement at all. Any idea ?

Comment: New iPerf results, iMac as server, MBP as client: [  4] local 192.168.1.56 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.43 port 58848
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.2 sec  95.6 MBytes  78.7 Mbits/sec

Comment: Now that you have an AP with Gigabit Ethernet, put the iMac on a Gigabit Ethernet LAN port of the AP, make it the IPerf server (as usual), and make the retina MacBook Pro the IPerf client (again with `-w 2M` on both sides. If the MBP sustains the 867 rate, you should see IPerf throughput in the 600Mbps range. Once we get the Wi-Fi performance problem tackled, we can move on to NAS (including SMB and AFP) performance.

Comment: Here's the new iPerf result, iMac plugged into Gigabit ethernet acting as iPerf server, MacBookPro connected via WiFi AC transmit rate at 878.  `Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 2.00 MByte
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 169.254.166.245 port 5001 connected with 169.254.123.203 port 60409
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.1 sec   177 MBytes   147 Mbits/sec
`

Comment: Are you still alive @Spiff ? :)

Comment: @Fred Unfortunately, this is where the troubleshooting may get difficult. You definitely have a Wi-Fi performance problem, but it's hard to say why. Try redoing that last test, but first make sure you're on the cleanest possible 5GHz channel, and make sure no other devices are joined to the 5GHz network when you do this. Note that 5GHz channels are grouped in groups of 4 to make an 80MHz channel, so for example channels 36, 40, 44, and 48 are all part of the same 80MHz channel. If you're on any of those 4 right now, switch to the 149/153/157/161 group.

Comment: I have changed the 5 GHz channel to 153, I have disconnected all other devices from the network, only the iMac is connected via gbit Lan and the MBP connected via the 5ghz wifi ac, transmit rate is again at 867, I'm getting the exact same numbers in iperf. On a side note, I live in a pretty remote location and there's not a single 2.4GHz or 5GHz Wi-Fi anywhere around me.

Answer (score 0):

My win7 box was reporting that my AC 5ghz connection was providing only a ~100 (or maybe 175) connection.  I opened the router GUI and changed the 5ghz bandwidth from automatic (20/40/80) to 80 and my connection went up to 300Mbps.

Windows may not be reporting accurately but, I know I feel better with 300 being reported as a connection speed over a 100 something speed.

In Windows7 - Click the WIFI Icon in the systray.  Right-click the connection name that you're on.  Choose STATUS and locate SPEED.

Answer (score -1):

It may be the USB drivers that is causing the problem. Until recently there was a bug in OSX Mavericks that caused 802.11ac file transfers to slow down. Try updating any of the usb drivers on the PCs. Also different protocols tend to get different speeds. Try using AFP or FTP but avoid SMB